# Is there a JS-like language which allows write access to local files?

Tags: javascript, perl, ms-access, local

I want to write a little program that will let me use a form to update some local files.

I can read them by making them json, but JS won't let me write local files.

I do this in Perl all the time, but it doesn't have a GUI for convenient input (short of trying to use some Tkx kludge)

Is there a language which will let me both use a GUI and write local files (and which supports hashes and regexs)?

Comment: Comedy "Java" reply :-)  Seriously, how about Python, or Tcl/Tk, or Ruby, or really a whole lot of other languages.

Comment: Oh also Scheme (with pregexp) :-)

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript *will* let you write local files, you just can't do it in browser-based JavaScript. Take [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) for example, you can read and write files no problem. So combine some HTML, client-side JavaScript, Ajax and "server-side" (run on the same machine) JavaScript to do what you need to do.

As for a language that lets you use a GUI, allows file access, and supports hashes and regular expressions... that's pretty much *every other mainstream language*. I personally would recommend Visual Basic.NET.

Comment: @user1067305: If you really want, depending on your needs, you can write a "zombie" GUI which will run in the browser and which simply sends all commands (like writing to local files) to e.g. Node.js running on the same computer. Then Node.js will actually execute all these commands. Then you're able to use a web GUI *and* to write to local files, both in JavaScript.

Comment: I don't want to pull a "Yes, But", but after experience running Tomcat and Lazslo to do some Flex programming, I'd really like to avoid having to run a local server. But I will look into some of the other languages you have suggested.

Comment: @user1067305: Node.js is much easier. No installation, really. Regardless, if you don't want to do that, go for some other language. VB.NET, C#, Java...?

Answer (score 3):

If you want Perl with JS GUI, why not have just that? Run a local web server with Perl code as a CGI script, and connect to it via a browser based front-end. Apache runs on both Linux and Windows and is a breeze to install. Just make sure to use some modern Perl web frameworks and not something ancient to ease your development.

Comment: Why bother with Apache for something like this?  [HTTP::Server::PSGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Server::PSGI) should be more than enough, and easier to set up.

Comment: @cjm - don't know how portable that is - no PSGI experience.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that google new dart language (with between js to java in syntax (mostly js), browser embedded etc) can do that. also I just [read](http://dartwatch.com/index.php/2011/11/exploring-dart-reading-and-writing-the-file-system/) about that here. never tried It by myself.

Answer (score 0):

If your GUI is Windows-based, try Microsoft's .NET framework.  You can get a simple GUI with Visual Basic or C# code running in a couple minutes.  And of course it can write to the local file system.